# Styled component doesn't override inline styles

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, styled-components, css-in-js

I'm trying to override third party component inline style.

I followed the doc [how can i override inline styles](https://styled-components.com/docs/faqs#how-can-i-override-inline-styles)

So, I used `&[style]` to override the inline style but this is not working.

The third party component I use is [CookieConsent](https://github.com/Mastermindzh/react-cookie-consent)

Right now, my component is looking like that:

```
import React from 'react';

import CookieConsent from 'react-cookie-consent';
import styled from 'styled-components';

const StyledCookieBanner = styled(CookieConsent)`
  &[style] {
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: calc(100% - 20px);
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 22px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 19px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.17);
  }
`;

const CookieBanner = (): React.ReactElement => {
  return (
    <StyledCookieBanner debug buttonText='Ok'>
      Cookie
    </StyledCookieBanner>
  );
};

export default CookieBanner;
```

I also tried [how can i override styles with higher specificity](https://styled-components.com/docs/faqs#how-can-i-override-styles-with-higher-specificity) without success.

The only way I found to override the style is doing something like that and use `!important`

```
const StyledCookieBanner = styled(CookieConsent)`
  > div {
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center !important;
    width: calc(100% - 20px) !important;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: white !important;
    border-radius: 22px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 19px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.17);
  }
`;
```

and also tried, without success

```
const StyledCookieBanner = styled(CookieConsent)`
  > div {
    // &&& {
    &[style] {
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      ...
    }
  }
`;
```

The docs seems pretty clear but I didn't succeed.

Did I miss something? Is that possible or should I use the `style` component props?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation page you linked:

> Inline styles will always take precedence over external CSS, so you cannot override it by simply increasing specificity.

Let's stop right there.  Styled Components adds *classes* to elements.  In HTML/CSS, `style` attribute styles will almost always trump class-based styles; there is nothing Styled Components (or any other class-based library) can do to change that ... unless you use a "hack" with `!important` that is ...

> There is a neat trick however, which is to use the style element-attr CSS Selector in conjunction with !important:

The `!important` is an essential part of that hack, and so the (working) code you posted:

```
const StyledCookieBanner = styled(CookieConsent)`
 > div {
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center !important;
    width: calc(100% - 20px) !important;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: white !important;
    border-radius: 22px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 19px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.17);
  }
`;
```

is both correct, and your only option.

If you really want to override `style` attributes ... override the style attributes :) Don't use Styled Components, use a `style` prop on your element (or in your case, ask `react-cookie-consent` to take a `style` prop to achieve that effect).

Comment: Is there a way to prevent support of the `style` prop on styled components?

Comment: That really seems like a separate Stack Overflow question, not a comment.